# Selecting rownum/max(rownum) with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq, rownum

I'm looking at a SQL query that uses Oracle's `rownum` pseudocolumn to select the row number as a fraction of the total rows:

```
ROWNUM/(MAX(ROWNUM) OVER())
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with a query written via jOOQ. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [Dmitry's `CUME_DIST()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235610/521799) is probably better suited for the actual query, here's the `ROWNUM` solution in jOOQ, for the record:

```
// Qualified
DSL.rownum().div(DSL.max(DSL.rownum()).over());

// With static imports of DSL.*
rownum().div(max(rownum()).over());
```

See also: [`DSL.rownum()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#rownum%28%29)

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Our older version of jOOQ doesn't have `rownum`.

Comment: Aha, it has been moved (duplicated) to `DSL` in a recent release. Before, it was in [`OracleDSL.rownum()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.1.x/org/jooq/util/oracle/OracleDSL.html#rownum()). If you're missing any specific feature, you can always resort to writing your own "`MyDSL`" object that provides `Fields` as [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I got your question right - is it that you need ?

```
SQL> select row_number() over(order by ename)/(count(*) over()) fraction from emp;

  FRACTION                                                                      
----------                                                                      
    .08333                                                                      
    .16667                                                                      
    .25000                                                                      
    .33333                                                                      
    .41667                                                                      
    .50000                                                                      
    .58333                                                                      
    .66667                                                                      
    .75000                                                                      
    .83333                                                                      
    .91667                                                                      
   1.00000
```

Also CUME_DIST analytic function can be useful:

```
SQL> SELECT ename, CUME_DIST()
  2     OVER (ORDER BY ename) fraction
  3     FROM emp
  4  /

ENAME        FRACTION                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
ALLEN          .08333                                                           
BLAKE          .16667                                                           
CLARK          .25000                                                           
FORD           .33333                                                           
JAMES          .41667                                                           
JONES          .50000                                                           
KING           .58333                                                           
MARTIN         .66667                                                           
MILLER         .75000                                                           
SMITH          .83333                                                           
TURNER         .91667                                                          
WARD          1.00000
```

Comment: Thanks - `CUME_DIST` is exactly what I needed, and jOOQ supports it directly.